# Chromium-browser always reports it didn't shut down properly

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, shutdown

Chromium-browser always reports it didn't shut down properly when I first start it after a shutdown/reboot.

I guess I could close it manually first before shutting down, but other apps seem to be ok with stopping themselves as the system shuts down, so why is chromium having a problem (and can it be fixed)?

Comment: Which version of Chromium are you using

Comment: It is the latest that 12.04 installed from the repos.18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I get this every time if I shutdown Ubuntu while Chromium/Chrome is open.  If I manually close it first, its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been a few updates for 12.04 and the problem seems to have gone away.  Maybe they fixed something.

Comment: I am now on 14.10 and I have the exact same problem...

Comment: I have the same problem in 14.04

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists try removing `rm -r ~/.config/chromium/`